# Multiple Definition Error when it doesnt seem to have multiple imports

Tags: c++, stb-image

So I have a couple of source and header files, and they all have this inheritance structure:

test.cpp -> mainengine.h -> object.h -> texture.h -> stb_image.h

The error goes as follows:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccneZuIO.o: in function `stbi_failure_reason':
mainengine.cpp:(.text+0x264): multiple definition of `stbi_failure_reason'; /tmp/ccxOxlHe.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x264): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccneZuIO.o: in function `stbi_image_free':
mainengine.cpp:(.text+0x55c): multiple definition of `stbi_image_free'; /tmp/ccxOxlHe.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x55c): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccneZuIO.o: in function `stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load':
mainengine.cpp:(.text+0x577): multiple definition of `stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load'; /tmp/ccxOxlHe.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x577): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccneZuIO.o: in function `stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load_thread':
mainengine.cpp:(.text+0x58a): multiple definition of `stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load_thread'; /tmp/ccxOxlHe.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x58a): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccneZuIO.o: in function `stbi_load':
mainengine.cpp:(.text+0xe44): multiple definition of `stbi_load'; /tmp/ccxOxlHe.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xe44): first defined here
```

and so on and so forth. It doesnt seem to make sense to me because I dont think I do multiple imports? 
 Here are the source files:

1. Test.cpp

```
#include "headers/mainengine.h"
int main(){
float vertices[] = {
    // positions          // colors           // texture coords
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,   // top right
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f    // top left 
    };
    unsigned int indices[] = {  // note that we start from 0!
        0, 1, 3,  // first Triangle
        1, 2, 3   // second Triangle
    };
    const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
    "layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;\n"
    "layout (location = 2) in vec3 aTexCoord;\n"
    "out vec3 ourColor;\n"
    "out vec2 TexCoord;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "gl_Position vec4(aPos,1.0);\n"
    "ourColor = aColor;\n"
    "TexCoord = aTexCoord;\n"
    "\n"
    "\n"
    "}\n\0";
    const char *fragShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
    "in vec3 ourColor;\n"
    "in vec2 TexCoord;\n"
    "uniform sampler2D ourTexture\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "FragColor = texture(ourTexture,TexCoord)\n"
    "}\n";
    std::list<object> objects;
    texture need("bliss.jpg",0,0,0);
    object real(vertices,vertexShaderSource,fragShaderSource,indices,need);
    objects.push_back(real);
    mainLoop("Game Test",600,800,objects);
}
```

2. mainengine.h

```
#include "../glad/include/glad/glad.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "object.h"
#include <list>
#ifndef MAINENGINE_H
#define MAINENGINE_H
void mainLoop(const char* name,int width,int height,std::list<object> objects);
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);
#endif
```

(mainengine.cpp only includes `mainengine.h`
3. object.h

```
#ifndef OBJECT_H
#define OBJECT_H
#include "texture.h"
class object{
    public:
        float vertices[100];
        unsigned int indices[100];
        texture tex;
        const char *vertexShaderSource;
        const char *fragShaderSource;
        object(float Basevertices[100],const char *BasevertexShaderSource,const char *BasefragShaderSource,unsigned int Baseindices[100], texture tex): tex(tex){
            unsigned int i;
            for(i = 0;i<100;i++){
                vertices[i] = Basevertices[i];
                std::cout<< "VERT : " << vertices[i] <<std::endl; 
            }
            for(i = 0;i<100;i++){
                indices[i] = Baseindices[i];
                std::cout<< "IND : " << indices[i] <<std::endl; 
            }
            vertexShaderSource = BasevertexShaderSource;
            fragShaderSource = BasefragShaderSource;
            this->tex = tex;
        }
        
};
#endif
```

4. texture.h

```
#ifndef TEXTURE_H
#define TEXTURE_H
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

class texture{
    public:
        unsigned char *data;
        texture(const char* name,int width, int height, int nrChannels){
            data = stbi_load(name, &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0); 
        }
};
#endif
```

Comment: `#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"` belongs in one cpp file, not a header that can be included multiple times. You'll find this explicit instruction at the top of the stb_image header. `Do this:
      #define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
   before you include this file in *one* C or C++ file to create the implementation.`

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: Your header guards should usually/generally be *before* your `#include`s.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you are placing the include. In the [documentation](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h), it says to include only in the implementations - or your `.c` and/or `.cpp` file which uses the stb command.